# SignedXml CheckSignature is returning false everytime

Tags: c#, security, saml, x509certificate, signedxml

We receive a SAML response from the client and when I am trying to validate the signature value using signedXml.CheckSignature(cert,true) then this method is returning always false.

I used the example code related to CheckSignature(X509Certificate2, Boolean) from this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml.checksignature?view=netframework-4.5.2#system-security-cryptography-xml-signedxml-checksignature(system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x509certificate2-system-boolean)) URL. Here, it will only create the SignedExample.xml file using a sample certificate and validated the signature successfully.

Created the certificate using the below command as mentioned in the MSDN example.

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=XMLDSIG_Test" -b 01/01/2005 -e 01/01/2010 -sky signing -ss my
```

If the same code runs with my original SAML response file using the same signature details of the sample certificate then CheckSignature method is returning false everytime.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

public class SignVerifyEnvelope
{

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {

        string Certificate = "CN=XMLDSIG_Test";

        try
        {

            // Create an XML file to sign.
            CreateSomeXml("Example.xml");
            Console.WriteLine("New XML file created.");

            // Sign the XML that was just created and save it in a
            // new file.
            SignXmlFile("Example.xml", "SignedExample.xml", Certificate);
            Console.WriteLine("XML file signed.");

            if (VerifyXmlFile("SignedExample.xml", Certificate))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The XML signature is valid.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The XML signature is not valid.");
            }


            //Testing My SAML response file
            if (VerifyXmlFile("SampleSamlResponse.xml", Certificate))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The XML signature is valid.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The XML signature is not valid.");
            }


        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    // Sign an XML file and save the signature in a new file.
    public static void SignXmlFile(string FileName, string SignedFileName, string SubjectName)
    {
        if (null == FileName)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("FileName");
        if (null == SignedFileName)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("SignedFileName");
        if (null == SubjectName)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("SubjectName");

        // Load the certificate from the certificate store.
        X509Certificate2 cert = GetCertificateBySubject(SubjectName);

        // Create a new XML document.
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        // Format the document to ignore white spaces.
        doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;

        // Load the passed XML file using it's name.
        doc.Load(new XmlTextReader(FileName));

        // Create a SignedXml object.
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);

        // Add the key to the SignedXml document.
        signedXml.SigningKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();

        // Create a reference to be signed.
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.Uri = "";

        // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
        XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(env);

        // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);

        // Create a new KeyInfo object.
        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();

        // Load the certificate into a KeyInfoX509Data object
        // and add it to the KeyInfo object.
        keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));

        // Add the KeyInfo object to the SignedXml object.
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

        // Compute the signature.
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

        // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
        // it to an XmlElement object.
        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

        // Append the element to the XML document.
        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

        if (doc.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration)
        {
            doc.RemoveChild(doc.FirstChild);
        }

        // Save the signed XML document to a file specified
        // using the passed string.
        using (XmlTextWriter xmltw = new XmlTextWriter(SignedFileName, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
        {
            doc.WriteTo(xmltw);
            xmltw.Close();
        }
    }

    // Verify the signature of an XML file against an asymmetric
    // algorithm and return the result.
    public static Boolean VerifyXmlFile(String FileName, String CertificateSubject)
    {
        // Check the args.
        if (null == FileName)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("FileName");
        if (null == CertificateSubject)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("CertificateSubject");

        // Load the certificate from the store.
        X509Certificate2 cert = GetCertificateBySubject(CertificateSubject);

        // Create a new XML document.
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

        // Load the passed XML file into the document.
        xmlDocument.Load(FileName);

        // Create a new SignedXml object and pass it
        // the XML document class.
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDocument);

        // Find the "Signature" node and create a new
        // XmlNodeList object.
        XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");

        // Load the signature node.
        signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

        // Check the signature and return the result.
        return signedXml.CheckSignature(cert, true);
    }

    public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateBySubject(string CertificateSubject)
    {
        // Check the args.
        if (null == CertificateSubject)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("CertificateSubject");

        // Load the certificate from the certificate store.
        X509Certificate2 cert = null;

        X509Store store = new X509Store("My", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

        try
        {
            // Open the store.
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

            // Get the certs from the store.
            X509Certificate2Collection CertCol = store.Certificates;

            // Find the certificate with the specified subject.
            foreach (X509Certificate2 c in CertCol)
            {
                if (c.Subject == CertificateSubject)
                {
                    cert = c;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Throw an exception of the certificate was not found.
            if (cert == null)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("The certificate could not be found.");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close the store even if an exception was thrown.
            store.Close();
        }

        return cert;
    }

    // Create example data to sign.
    public static void CreateSomeXml(string FileName)
    {
        // Check the args.
        if (null == FileName)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("FileName");

        // Create a new XmlDocument object.
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

        // Create a new XmlNode object.
        XmlNode node = document.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "", "MyElement", "samples");

        // Add some text to the node.
        node.InnerText = "Example text to be signed.";

        // Append the node to the document.
        document.AppendChild(node);

        // Save the XML document to the file name specified.
        using (XmlTextWriter xmltw = new XmlTextWriter(FileName, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
        {
            document.WriteTo(xmltw);

            xmltw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my Sample SAML Response file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="_3b7df14a-0f79-4289-8cb8-efc3bace841c" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2020-09-08T17:04:28.018Z" Destination="https://somewhere.abc/adminsso.do">
   <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://sts.windows.net/qwertyui-sdfg-4f45-a6d0-asdfghjklqwe/</Issuer>
   <samlp:Status>
      <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
   </samlp:Status>
   <Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_asdfghjk-2345-5678-asdf-asdfghjklzxc" IssueInstant="2020-09-08T17:04:28.013Z" Version="2.0">
      <Issuer>https://sts.windows.net/qwertyui-sdfg-4f45-a6d0-asdfghjklqwe/</Issuer>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
         <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <Reference URI="#_asdfghjk-2345-5678-asdf-asdfghjklzxc">
               <Transforms>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
               </Transforms>
               <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
               <DigestValue>Kglqb8fjGmMi2n4W8qXldBIY7VBi0xbNn+dZml7H3xw=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
         </SignedInfo>
         <SignatureValue>kAB5IaPijVsotG8UdbjBu8AYXCOE6vS+fruPlidSxqIUyzRMlLAsOG2iVEHbBPIWWF2Ujjs7PdQ1cZzPg3LhwHVMam9PRnxbUaqoI+RTqudtXS3Fk4zwpsbvPw0LctQdzelwZTFIK/8iiEh/MA+dqSlw/3r2c8rpsMPH59P4tnp7bxPDTXnAEiHvFPKmTswT5fq65ltvhbz5hI+pGAdtB1GMBrVpFnloOFi6Vl2aObDhlAwd4gNuNoKL/UvefWi4olPMIQeZMzKpjXpd7Y8xM40aI2ZCTYyvrZLxRUSH/rhmktdV9WTVUAKOeJK7N3v0qm8ugErthVsi07R1nTISNw==</SignatureValue>
         <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
               <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
         </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
      <Subject>
         <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">abc@domain.com</NameID>
         <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
            <SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2024-09-08T18:04:27.810Z" Recipient="https://somewhere.abc/adminsso.do" />
         </SubjectConfirmation>
      </Subject>
      <Conditions NotBefore="2020-09-08T16:59:27.810Z" NotOnOrAfter="2024-09-08T18:04:27.810Z">
         <AudienceRestriction>
            <Audience>https://somewhere.abc</Audience>
         </AudienceRestriction>
      </Conditions>
      <AttributeStatement>
         <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid">
            <AttributeValue>qwertyui-sdfg-4f45-a6d0-asdfghjklqwe</AttributeValue>
         </Attribute>
         <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier">
            <AttributeValue>9a45ea45-6122-443a-8e01-45dc9a89e589</AttributeValue>
         </Attribute>
         <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname">
            <AttributeValue>sample, abc</AttributeValue>
         </Attribute>
         <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider">
            <AttributeValue>https://sts.windows.net/qwertyui-sdfg-4f45-a6d0-asdfghjklqwe/</AttributeValue>
         </Attribute>
         <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname">
            <AttributeValue>sample</AttributeValue>
         </Attribute>
         <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname">
            <AttributeValue>abc</AttributeValue>
         </Attribute>
         <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
            <AttributeValue>abc@domain.com</AttributeValue>
         </Attribute>
         <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name">
            <AttributeValue>sample</AttributeValue>
         </Attribute>
      </AttributeStatement>
      <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2020-09-08T12:29:35.621Z" SessionIndex="_asdfghjk-2345-5678-asdf-asdfghjklzxc">
         <AuthnContext>
            <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</AuthnContextClassRef>
         </AuthnContext>
      </AuthnStatement>
   </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

save the above file as SampleSamlResponse.xml in debug folder.

I am not getting what I am missing. I am using .Net framework 4.8

Please help.

**Update:**

one thing I observed is that the code is working fine with the below Saml response (saml2p:resposne) but I need the code to work with first saml respose (samlp:resposne) file because we receive that from the client

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_a768f8de-d02c-4c61-9589-d7cc063d012a" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2022-12-08T14:17:44.988Z" Destination="http://somewhere/">
   <saml2:Issuer>sample-issuer</saml2:Issuer>
   <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <SignedInfo>
         <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
         <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
         <Reference URI="#_a768f8de-d02c-4c61-9589-d7cc063d012a">
            <Transforms>
               <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
               <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <DigestValue>ap5YvbiOn91+4yyezmOilHJUyhzQ1mEDCjEfTQ/Zy+k=</DigestValue>
         </Reference>
      </SignedInfo>
      <SignatureValue>dmrmEyCaf9PWG4Tx9KIyXyYy8YWdDai3fXjvtFVGl9NDHYIDKzuGUMtMxNFLiIWL4g/DlTG/V8TOyjh4HeJSqB8W4T7G3bDdVeOKpLWphWgn/87S1BEah3A9dvg29654kPNZhSQz5IF9wkWecN4pSMzlf4O85jFkcYq6DBVuw+3F2hSzrNWzB3bF4DGWBnpZE35gsjwS8MwPyZ1iIxIR+WTCmRi0OuHJVYIzNIIL5V/sP5JjhtGd6PwtKKZ1SpqcHNqoqTMV9hyXBwJK0EIacvIH3pGvqJAt7Yz6FRhJ1EADKymB/MVDdeKIO0m75/azeWVx6mPuIgzpF2zAdva9aA==</SignatureValue>
      <KeyInfo>
         <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
         </X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
   </Signature>
   <saml2p:Status>
      <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
   </saml2p:Status>
   <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_0449d2d8-5722-4c20-861f-056ddbb6c7fe" IssueInstant="2022-12-08T14:17:45.060Z" Version="2.0">
      <saml:Issuer>sample-issuer</saml:Issuer>
      <saml:Subject>
         <saml:NameID>sample abc</saml:NameID>
         <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
            <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2022-12-08T14:22:45.160Z" Recipient="http://somewhere" />
         </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
      </saml:Subject>
      <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2022-12-08T14:17:45.113Z" NotOnOrAfter="2022-12-08T15:17:45.028Z">
         <saml:AudienceRestriction>
            <saml:Audience>http://somewhere</saml:Audience>
         </saml:AudienceRestriction>
      </saml:Conditions>
      <saml:AttributeStatement>
         <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
            <saml:AttributeValue>abc@domain.com</saml:AttributeValue>
         </saml:Attribute>
         <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/locality">
            <saml:AttributeValue>somewhere</saml:AttributeValue>
         </saml:Attribute>
      </saml:AttributeStatement>
      <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2022-12-08T14:17:45.157Z">
         <saml:AuthnContext>
            <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
         </saml:AuthnContext>
      </saml:AuthnStatement>
   </saml:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace characters are significant when generating/verifying XML signatures.

You must set xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace to true in your VerifyXmlFile method.

If you're looking to verify XML signatures as part of SAML SSO in a production environment, I strongly recommend using a commercial or open source SAML library as there are XML Signature Wrapping (XSW) and other related attacks that must be handled.

Comment: I tried with xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true also but still facing the same issue.